# Electric field with Maxwell's 1st equation

Tags: electromagnetism

With a total charge Q within a radius R the problem is to find the electric field at a radius r>R and r<R. The charge density is within the radius R proportional to 1 / r and zero outside (uniform charge distribution both in-and outside R).

I'm trying to use Maxwell’s 1st equation: Coulomb’s law , but struggling getting it right and I think there are some facts missing for me.

Comment: Try using the symmetry and the divergence theorem.

Comment: @hanban if you need help, please edit the question with your working.